# xero c# "The current TokenRepository doesn't have a current request token"

Tags: c#, oauth

Have managed to connect to xero API and get an request token. however after restarting the project (for debugging), it mostly gives the following error when asking for an Access Token

`The current TokenRepository doesn't have a current request token`

as per my understanding and observation, the error is randomly raised. i.e sometimes it shows and sometimes it doesnt. the relevant code is as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        IOAuthSession oauthSession = ServiceProvider.GetCurrentSession();
        //
        // GET: /Home/


        public ActionResult XeroConnect()
        {
            Session.Clear();

            Repository repository = ServiceProvider.GetCurrentRepository();

            oauthSession.MessageLogger = new DebugMessageLogger();


            // Can we already access an organisation??
            if (oauthSession.HasValidAccessToken && repository != null && repository.Organisation != null)
            {
                return new RedirectResult("~/");
            }

            if (oauthSession is XeroApiPrivateSession)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("The current private session cannot access the authorised organisation. Has the access token been revoked?");
            }


            var callbackUri = new UriBuilder(Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.Port, "Home/Callback");
            RequestToken requestToken = oauthSession.GetRequestToken(callbackUri.Uri);

        string authorisationUrl = oauthSession.GetUserAuthorizationUrl();

            return new RedirectResult(authorisationUrl);
        }

        public ActionResult Callback()
        {
            string verificationCode = Request.Params["oauth_verifier"];
            AccessToken accessToken = oauthSession.ExchangeRequestTokenForAccessToken(verificationCode); // error shows here

            GetAndStoreAuthorisedOrganisationName();

            Repository repository = ServiceProvider.GetCurrentRepository();

           List<XeroApi.Model.Invoice> invoices = (from invoice in repository.Invoices
                          where invoice.LineItems.Count > 0
                          select invoice).ToList();

            return View(invoices);
        }
}
```

any help appreciated. am also clearing the sessions before a new request token is asked for.

Comment: Xero Partner api has serious issues.  After spending days with all kind of trial and errors and trick, no luck renewing the token.  Xero api customer service is either non-existent or provide bogus answers.  You don't get responses for days and when they respond, you don't get much out of them.

Comment: As to this error, if this is a Private App using private app api, upon receiving this error, ask user to login to Xero again (that is, go through the same routine that you did to obtain original token).

Comment: The issue here is not Xero. It is your `oauthSession` loosing the request token before the callback is called from Xero. You should go for a persistent token manager solution instead.